# Setting a Php Cookies timer to expire after 24hr

Tags: php, html, cookies

I have created a PHP function which technically should expire/reset after 24hrs. PHP seems to store cache which so what hinders the cookies timer.

Below is a snippet of my code, which is essentially a cookie timer. When the users presses the 'close-reveal-modal' class the cookie popup does not appear for 24hr.

```
if( !isset($_COOKIE["saw-popup"]) && $_COOKIE["saw-popup"] != "true") {
    $one_day_in_seconds = 60*60*24;
    setcookie("saw-popup", "true", time() + $one_day_in_seconds);

    if (is_front_page()) {
        get_template_part('partials/modal', 'homepage-newsletter-signup');
    }
}
```

Is there anything I can add to this function to ensure the timer correctly resets after a 24hr period?

Comment: **OR** `if( !isset($_COOKIE["saw-popup"]) || $_COOKIE["saw-popup"] != "true") {`

Comment: @RiggsFolly write this in an answer please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your test is not going to work the way you have it.

Try an OR instead

```
if( !isset($_COOKIE["saw-popup"]) || $_COOKIE["saw-popup"] != "true") {
```

So now we are saying, if the cookie does not exist OR the cookie is not equal to "true".

Comment: It should do, although the browser is what controls the removal of a cookie once the time limit is reached